# Gunpla, matte plastic shader

Tags: materials, shaders

Is there way to create shader like Gunpla's plastic like below images?

Its not a shiny plastic, but more of matte + airbrush grains.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ..it's not just the material and bumped-up ambient occlusion.. it's also the lighting. and choice of palette..

Comment: I think you have to specify more what you want to achieve since those images are not high enough in detail to understand the exact thing you have in mind. To me, it looks like a plain plastic surface, nothing stands out of the ordinary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts ah got it, I wanted to know if there a way to produce similar look. Thank you for the comment. I will experiment on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick node setup for this look. Tho it depends on the color and lighting, use the AO to highlight the dark gaps in the figures, a subtle noise texture for the airbrushed look, play with the roughness and subsurface to get the aesthetic u want, rest is pretty straightforwad I hope! [image]

Comment: Thanks! I will give a go and tweak with it :)